# how to see previous value of a field in salesforce edited by mistake

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, history-tracking, field-history, track

I edited by mistake the value of a field. The track history of the custom object isn't enable.
Can i do something to see the the old value? Maybe with a query.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try looking into audit history.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you don't have history tracking enabled *and are specifically tracking that field*, then that value is lost.

Your only other potential saving graces here would be:

- You have a backup (an export) of the relevant data
- You have a full copy or partial copy sandbox (the data for your record *may* exist and have your desired data. Depends on if the target record had the target data at the time of the last sandbox refresh)